# Nested Unordered Menu clicks on Ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, menu, touch

I have a nested menu list like below. At the moment, when someone clicks the main menu item, it follows that link. I was wondering if there is a way to get touchscreens to display the drop down menu without following the main menu item? The submenu has been styled ot display when the main menu item is hovered over

- Main Menu Item

  - Sub Menu Item

Comment: Not clear what you want to ask?

Comment: @A.K I have added some more info.

Comment: so you may use jQuery accordian: reference link: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to do as mentioned in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/rvy6U/

**NOTE: `hover` event is not present in touch devices, while `tap` event is present in touch devices. `tap` and `click` events behaves same.**

**jQuery**

```
$('#accordion li').click(function(){

    if($('.sub').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).find('a').next('.sub').stop().slideToggle('slow')
    } else {
        $(this).find('a').next('.sub').stop().slideToggle('slow')    
    }

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li><a href="#">Section 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>Mauris mauris ante</li> 
            <li>blandit et, ultrices a</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Section 2</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>Mauris mauris ante</li> 
            <li>blandit et, ultrices a</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sub {
    display: none;
}​
```

Comment: But, what about if the main menu item has a href?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery onClick() to display the submenu I think.

You current hover function would still work on desktop computers and the onClick() would work for touchscreen devices and desktop computers too.